# Trouble with floats and small screens

Tags: html, css

I am writing a web app, and am having some trouble with scaling the content to iPhone sizes. I have set my buttons:

```
<div class="form_divs" id="metal_buttons">
    <button class="btn" id="btn-bronze" name="bronze" type="button">Bronze</button>
    <button class="btn" id="btn-silver" name="silver" type="button">Silver</button>
    <button class="btn" id="btn-gold" name="gold" type="button">Gold</button>
</div>
```

that use the `float:left` *CSS* property, resulting in the desired look (all buttons side-by-side, no spaces)

[fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/PhDBrown/zWfT8/)

```
#metal_buttons {
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 4%;
    margin-left: 4%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.btn {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.0, #F8F8F8), color-stop(1.0, #AAAAAA));
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

however on my iPhone, this causes the buttons to wrap to the next line.

If I remove the `float: left` property, the line no longer wraps, but there are spaces between my buttons:

[fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/PhDBrown/vLn93/1/)

```
#metal_buttons {
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 4%;
    margin-left: 4%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.btn {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.0, #F8F8F8), color-stop(1.0, #AAAAAA));
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

What can I do to have the behavior of the first fiddle (no spacing between buttons), while preventing these buttons from line-wrapping on a small screen (by, for example, scaling down)?

Comment: have a look at media queries (and personnaly i think the buttons should wrap, nobody likes scrolling, definitly not horizontally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the mobile look you should put

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #your mobile css goes here
}
```

so you can have different style with the same name to look good on both mobile and other platforms

you can go  [@media](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) 
for more info

Comment: I'd even go so far as to recommend using Zurb's framework Foundation — http://foundation.zurb.com — which helps making deal with layout issues a little easier for multiple display types.